# Generate mule_export.properties with Maven

Tags: maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to set up IntelliJ to deploy Mule project that depends on a domain project, but the result builded by Maven does not have **META-INF** directory and **mule_export.properties** in it. However, the same build within AnyPoint Studio does produce these artifacts, which make the deployment successful.

Does anyone know how can I force Maven to create these? Either through Maven plugin or IntelliJ associations, as it seems that associations within IDE are the reason this is being produced by AnyPoint Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need the mule_export.properties. It seems to be only generated by Anypoint Studio when exporting a project. However I don't think it is used at all to deploy an application. Probably you are having a different problem. Usually that happens by differences between Maven dependencies and Studio build path.

What is the exact error you are having at deployment?

Comment: Turns out you are 100% right, for some reason Maven build is missing about 50 jars that are included during build in Anypoint Studio. The jars seem to come from a domain project that is marked as dependency in Anypoint Studio, but is not a dependency in POM. It looks like there is no was to reproduce this behavior with IntelliJ plugin, listing the project as domain dependency in POM of the app didn't help either. Do you have any suggestions what direction I might take in search for an answer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Intellij plugin but the application should build as a Maven project by Intellij Maven support. I'm not sure what issue are you having after adding the domain. Could you expand the description about that?